# ACF + Time Picker - Can Not Return Time As String Value

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, php-7.1

Ok I am officially at wits end, hoping someone can assist with my code. Just started wading into PHP and ACF and I am attempting to pull from custom values on a custom post type "events" that has various information contained within it.

The statement I am trying to make is that:

if the event is a multiple day event, notated by the value **"multi"** in the **"event_type"** field, then the **"event_start"** and **"event_end"** dates are pulled and formatted so as to read *"EVENT_START to EVENT_END"*.

If the value for **"event_type"** is not **"multi"** (it would be "single"), then I want to display the **"event_start"** date and then the from and to times stored in the time picker objects **"event_start_time"** and **"event_end_time"** respectively.

I've got the dates part of it working, as well as the selection piece based on the value, but for the life of me I can't get the times to show up.

Here's the code:

```
$event_type = get_field('event_type');
$start_date = get_field('event_date');
$end_date = get_field('event_end_date');
$end_time = get_field('event_end_time');
$str_start_time = date("g:i a", strtotime($start_time));
$str_end_time = date("g:i a", strtotime($end_time));
$str_start_date = date("F j, Y", strtotime($start_date));
$str_end_date = date("F j, Y", strtotime($end_date));

if ($event_type=='multi'){
    echo ($str_start_date . " to " . $str_end_date);
}
else{
    echo $str_start_date . " from " . $str_start_time . " to " . $str_end_time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was able to get this figured out for the most part, but still having an issue where the datetime for the first date reverts to UNIX time and 1970 as the date. Heres the updated code:

```
<div class="row" align="center"><h3>WHEN</h3></div>
<?php
$event_type = get_field('event_type');
$start_date = get_field('event_start');
$start_date = date("F j, Y g:i a", strtotime($start_date));
$start_date_only = new DateTime($start_date);
$start_date_only = $start_date_only->format('F j, Y');
$start_time_only = new DateTime($start_date);
$start_time_only = $start_time_only->format('g:i a');
$end_date = get_field('event_end_date');
$end_date = date("F j, Y g:i a", strtotime($end_date));
$end_date_only = new DateTime($end_date);
$end_date_only = $end_date_only->format('F j, Y');
$end_time_only = new DateTime($end_date);
$end_time_only = $end_time_only->format('g:i a');

ob_start(); //Start output buffer
echo $start_date_only . " to " . $end_date_only;
$start_end_date = ob_get_contents(); //Grab output
ob_end_clean(); //Discard output buffer
ob_start(); //Start output buffer
echo $start_date_only . " from " . $start_time_only . " to " . $end_time_only;
$date_and_time = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); //Discard output buffer
?>

<div class="row" align="center"><h3><?php echo "$start_end_date"; ?></h3></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="row" align="center"><h3>WHERE</h3></div>
<div class="row" align="center"><h3><?php the_field('event_location_name') ?><br><?php the_field('event_location_address'); ?></h3></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Final update, the code works, I just needed to remove the repeater from its nested position in a group for the fields to display properly and for the UNIX time to convert.